# Merge Irregular Time Based Data Series

Tags: google-sheets, merge, time-series, merging-data

I would like to merge 2 Google sheets (**INPUT #1 & INPUT #2**) into 1 sheet (**OUTPUT**). These 3 sheets are enclosed in the same Google Spreadsheet.

On a daily basis, Sheets **INPUT #1 & INPUT #2** are updated by the end of the data series.

**OUTPUT** should adapt automatically.

Can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
={INPUT1!A1:C1,INPUT2!B1:C1;
 {QUERY({INPUT1!A2:D}, "select Col1,Col2,Col3,' ',Col4 where Col1 is not null label ' '''");
  QUERY({INPUT2!A2:D}, "select Col1,' ','  ',Col2,Col3 where Col1 is not null label ' ''','  '''")}}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Sure @player0 here you are: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SXzaGh0a9vwHov16z4clxFubt1UMiL0u3isLpay7fRo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: that's a label part where I "name" label to be empty - otherwise, you would have there 2 more rows. you can try to check it out how it looks like when you remove `label ' '''` from a query